# How inputs are mapped to outputs in Super Resolution GAN?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59693504/is-it-possible-to-give-variable-input-shape-while-training-super-resolution-gans) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58192050/keras-multiple-input-output-loss-model) questions on Super Resolution GAN, I don't understand to what model is mapped the high resolution image, and why is it passed as input of the combined model?

Taking the code from the second linked question:

```
# Build and compile the discriminator
self.discriminator = self.build_discriminator()
self.discriminator.compile(loss='mse',
        optimizer=optimizer,
        metrics=['accuracy'])


# Build the generator
self.generator = self.build_generator()

# High res. and low res. images
img_hr = Input(shape=self.hr_shape, name="HR")
img_lr = Input(shape=self.lr_shape, name="LR")

# Generate high res. version from low res.
fake_hr = self.generator(img_lr)

# Extract image features of the generated img
fake_features = self.vgg(fake_hr)

# For the combined model we will only train the generator
self.discriminator.trainable = False

# Discriminator determines validity of generated high res. images
validity = self.discriminator(fake_hr)

self.combined = Model([img_lr, img_hr], [validity, fake_features])
self.combined.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy', 'mse'],
                          loss_weights=[1e-3, 1],
                          optimizer=optimizer)
```

If I print the summary of the combined model, I can see that HR layer is not connected to any model:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
LR (InputLayer)                 [(None, 64, 64, 3)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Generator (Functional)          (None, 256, 256, 3)  27470659    LR[0][0]                         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
HR (InputLayer)                 [(None, 256, 256, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Discriminator (Functional)      (None, 16, 16, 1)    5219137     Generator[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
VGG19 (Functional)              (None, 64, 64, 256)  1735488     Generator[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 34,425,284
Trainable params: 27,466,435
Non-trainable params: 6,958,849
```

Which gives:

- LR -> Generator -> Discriminator -> validity
- LR -> Generator -> VGG19 -> fake_features

So, what `img_hr` is used for on that line `Model([img_lr, img_hr], [validity, fake_features])`?

*Note*:

- *Full code: https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/srgan/srgan.py*
- *Paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.04802*